# Why are my textures inside out?

Tags: texturing, eevee-render-engine, .fbx

[image: 1]

I am using an FBX model that comes with textures, but when I try and view the model in material preview, the textures appear inside the model, like it's flipped inside out. Keep in mind it works fine in solid view and rendered view (Cycles).

[image: 2]

EEVEE seems to be the only problem. I'm fairly new to Blender, so a descriptive explanation would be helpful. I included a photo of the problem, and the model if you need it. The model in question is ["\Nintendo Switch - Super Smash Bros Ultimate - Ness\Ness\ness.fbx"](https://www.models-resource.com/nintendo_switch/supersmashbrosultimate/model/29323/)

Comment: In the material properties on the right side, scroll down to where it says Blend Mode. Look for options such as "Backface Culling" and/or "Show Backface". Try enabling/disabling them.

Comment: Thank you! This helped!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your materials are set to *Blend Mode > Alpha Blend* which creates transparency in Eevee, you need to switch to *Edit* mode, select a face of the mesh that has the material you want to change (it will automatically select the material in the material list), and under *Settings > Blend Mode*, switch to *Opaque* (or disable the *Show Backface* option). I don't know if there's a way to switch all the materials to opaque at once, maybe you need a python script.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work. Did you find a solution with your model?

Comment: yes, it works for me, you need to make sure that you've selected the good material, when in Edit mode, select one face of the mesh, then switch to Opaque

Comment: Thank you so much! I worked!